# create links in AS3 with PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, air

I've got this code that retrieve data from my SQL Data Base into my AS3 code.

My table (data base) has this rows : "id", "title", "price", "information", "mail".

In my AS3 code I loaded "title".

**Php Code :**

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Last-Modified: $ts");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");


 $num = mysql_numrows($sql_result);
$phptheTitle = "";
$obj = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
 $theTitle = $row["theTitle"];
   $phptheTitle = $phptheTitle.' </br> '.$theTitle;
    $datas = array();
     $datas['theTitle'] = $row["theTitle"];
     $datas['prix'] = $row["prix"];
      $obj[] = $datas;
 } 

echo json_encode( array('products' => $obj) );

 mysql_free_result($sql_result);
 mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

**AS3 code :**

```
function categorieSelected(evt:Event):void {
                var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("http://www.mywebsite.com/find_annonces.php");
                urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
                var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
                urlReq.data = urlVars;  
                trace("typeSelected");
                urlVars.categorie = evt.target.value;
                trace(urlVars.categorie);
                varLoader2.load(urlReq);


    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader (urlReq); 
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES; 
    loader.load(urlReq); 
            trace(urlReq);
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
        }



function loadComplete(evt:Event):void {
    trace("loadComplete");
    var myResult:String = evt.target.data;
    trace(myResult);    
    output_txt.htmlText = myResult;
    var datas     :Object = JSON.parse( myResult );
    var products  :Array = datas && datas.products ? datas.products : [];


var len:int = products.length;
for( var i:int = 0; i<len; ++i ){
     trace( products[i].title, products[i].price );
}
}
```

So my output_txt is displaying all items in the row "title".

Now, is it possible to create a link for each title(in AS3) ? 
In order to display "price", "information", "mail" when we click on the title(each title has their own "price", "information" and "mail", contain in my database).

Exemple : 
The AS3 code displays "Computer". When I click on "ipod Touch" it displays "price", "information" and "mail" that is contains in my database.

Here's a short video of what I'd like to do  : http://sendvid.com/whdm4sjf

---

EDIT

So with the help of Aaron, the code works a little bit better.

In my AS3, the user can choose a "categorie" in order to displays all the titles contains in the categorie.

For that I've put this `$categorie = $_POST['categorie'];` in PHP

And this code in AS3

```
var loader5:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var varLoader2:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
varLoader2.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varLoader2.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler2);

        function categorieSelected(evt:Event):void {
                var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("http://www.brousse-en-folie.com/sondage/convertXML.php");
                urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
                var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
                urlReq.data = urlVars;  
                trace("typeSelected");
                urlVars.categorie = evt.target.value;
                varLoader2.load(urlReq);



loader5.load(new URLRequest("http://www.brousse-en-folie.com/sondage/convertXML.php"));
loader5.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete);

        }
```

But it seems that with the JSON loading, there is a conflict and I've got this error with the function `categorieSelected`

```
Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.
```

Here's a short video of the problem : http://sendvid.com/18rr26rb

Comment: You can definitely do this. As it is, though, your question is probably too broad. AS3 does not have a built in concept of "links" or "pages", and there's a ton of different ways you could achieve this kind of thing.

Comment: Thx for the answer. And can you give me one or 2 exemples to do that please ? like .....`addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showData)`, `function showData{ how the code can know and show me the data of the evt.target ? as it can be 100 different target I won't make 100 hyperlinks. Can it automatically search for the corresponding data ?`

Comment: Can you edit your question with all of your relevant code? I also don't know what you mean by "I won't make 100 hyperlinks"?

Comment: I've edited my post by adding a short video explaining what I'd like to do. It will be clearer with a video.

Comment: Slower video : http://sendvid.com/whdm4sjf

Comment: @user3094896 What you are looking for is not "links", you want just to show ads (annonces in french) by category and then show each ad's details. Here I think that's better to return an XML (or JSON) content from your PHP script then parse it into an Array (for example) which you can use after that to show any needed information (categories, ad's details, ...) ...

Comment: I agree with @akmozo, you should just return raw data (XML or JSON) and render it out in Flash in the appropriate way. Right now you are combining all your titles into a single HTML string, but that limits what Flash can do with it.

Comment: @user3094896 You should return a valid JSON content (without any other content), so here you should remove this : `echo  "phptheTitle=" . $phptheTitle;` (and any other output other than for the JSON) and don't forget the `Content-Type` header : `header('Content-type: application/json');` and the cache also ...

Comment: Thx. So, how I added the Content-Type. Removed the "echo phptheTitle" (But what do I do with this line in my AS3 if I remove the echo phptheTitle ? : `var myResult:String = evt.target.data.phptheTitle;` )  But I don't know how to "cache" JSON in Php (if it what you meant).

Comment: Maybe it'd be simpler by converting it into an XML instead ?

Comment: @user3094896 You don't need `evt.target.data.phptheTitle`, you have just to use `evt.target.data`. For the cache, take a look on this [post](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-caching-headers/) for example ...

Comment: Thx. I followed the exemple. Still an error (not the same though) :  `Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs. ` Must be in my php file, but weirdly it's working when I load the php in my web Browser.

Comment: @user3094896 Could you show your AS3 code (the part which is loading the JSON data) ?

Comment: I've edited my post and put it in "EDIT 3"

Comment: @user3094896 Don't echo "phptheTitle=", just echo the JSON data, ie it must be wrapped in `[ ]` or `{ }` to be valid JSON.

Comment: I've already deleted "phptheTitle=". But what do you mean wrapped in [ ] ? I do I do that ? (since the data are taken in my database).

Comment: I've edited the all post with the current code (with all modifications since the begining of this post).

Comment: Don't set `loader.dataFormat = VARIABLES`, you want `TEXT` (which is the default) because the data from the server is JSON text, not url variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough idea of what I would do:

1. Return *all* your data as XML or JSON. For example you can use PHP `json_encode` to return the SQL results as JSON.
2. Load the JSON into AS3 using `URLLoader` and `JSON.parse`.
3. Now you have an `Array` of data you can iterate over and display list items.
4. Add a click handler to each display list item that will hide the list, and show a detailed view.

You can accomplish this many ways, here's one simple example:

**PHP**

```
$products = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
    $products[] = array(
        "title" => $row["theTitle"],
        "price" => $row["thePrice"]
    );
} 

echo json_encode($products);
```

Which should output valid JSON like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Product 1",
        "price": 100
    },
    {
        "title": "Product 2",
        "price": 200
    },
    {
        "title": "Product 3",
        "price": 300
    }
]
```

**AS3**

Load the JSON and render it out:

```
var products:Array;

var list:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(list);

var details:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(details);

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("products.php"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete);

function complete(e:Event):void {
    products = JSON.parse(loader.data) as Array;

    for(var i:int = 0; i < products.length; i++){
        createListItem(i, products[i]);
    }

    showList();
}

function createListItem(index:int, item:Object):void {
    var listItem:TextField = new TextField();
    listItem.text = item.title;
    listItem.y = index * 20;
    listItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
        showDetails(item);
    });
    list.addChild(listItem);
}

function showList():void {
    details.visible = false;
    list.visible = true;
}

function showDetails(item:Object):void {
    list.visible = false;
    details.visible = true;

    details.text = "Price: " + item.price + "\nInformation: " + item.information + "\nMail: " + item.mail;
}
```

This is just a rough start to give you an idea.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I'll try that and let you know. First time I'm using a connection between AS3 and an SQL so I'll try. I'm gonna look up for the first part, first. Return all my data as XML or JSON.

Comment: @user3094896 Don't echo the `phpthetitle=`, just return valid JSON, in other words it must be wrapped with `[ ]` or `{ }`.

Comment: I've edited the all post (to be more clear and find more easily where the error is). I still have this error : `Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.`

Comment: @user3094896 I updated my answer to include everything from PHP to AS3.

Comment: Don't set `URLLoader` `dataFormat` to `VARIABLES`, because the format is JSON you want it to be `TEXT` and to parse it using `JSON.parse(text)`.

Comment: Thx. I'll try that. Where do I put the second part ? ("_Which should output valid JSON like this:_") Just after `echo json_encode($products);` ?

Comment: That's just an example of valid JSON I would expect the PHP to output from `json_encode($products)`. It's what you should see in your browser, and in AS3 when `URLLoader` completes. Notice how it's *just* valid JSON. That's important, because in AS3 the `JSON.parse()` expects *only* valid JSON text, nothing more.

Comment: I've tried the code you gave me in your answer. It results with  `Error 1119 : Access of possibly undefined property data through a reference with static type flash.display:Loader` For this line    `products = JSON.parse(loader.data) as Array;`

Comment: You're using a `Loader` but you should use a `URLLoader` as my code does.

Comment: I just paste your code (nothing else). I see in line 5 `products = JSON.parse(loader.data) as Array;` That not what you meant ?

Comment: That's what I meant: `loader` is a variable which, in my code, is typed to `URLoader` which has a `data` property for the loaded data, it is not a `Loader`. It sounds like you have a `Loader` somewhere. You can use whatever variable names you want, just  make sure the loader for the JSON is a `URLLoader` not a `Loader`.

Comment: You were right, I had another `loader` in a previous frame. Thx. So now it's working better. Titles are displayed and I can click on them but it displays an error `Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.`

Comment: Ok it seems to be the variable "categorie" that I send to my php that causing this bug. But I need to send the variable when choosing the categorie in my ComboBox in AS3. How can I do ? For the moment I've got this code     `var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("http://www.brousse-en-folie.com/sondage/convertXML.php");
    urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
    var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
    urlReq.data = urlVars;  
    urlVars.categorie = evt.target.value;
    varLoader2.load(urlReq);`

Comment: Everything is working GREAT so thank you very much. I just got this problem with my comboBox and sending the variable "categorie" but that's all. If you know the solution don't hesitate. Otherwise I will create a now post for this problem. Thx again

Comment: That error makes it sound like you still have a `URLLoader` with `dataType = VARIABLES` somewhere, which would fail since the response is not url-encoded variables, it's JSON text. You can still send a `URLRequest` with your `categorie` as `URLVariables`.

Comment: Is there a way to "empty" the list ? (if I change the category, the old item list is still visible). Like calling a "removeListItem" function before calling again the function createListItem.

Comment: You can use `removeChildren()` to remove all the children, then re-create all the items.

Comment: even with `removeChild(list)` and then `addChild(list)`, the child reapears with the old list. I've tried to erase the memory of list with `list = null;` but I can't call it back after that...

Comment: I meant `list.removeChildren()`, this will remove all the list items, then you can re-create all the items with the current products array.

Comment: Perfect. And, at last, any idea why the code doesn't work on Android device ? Works perfectly on my desktop and display the list but on my Android tablet, the list is not displayed when I choose the category... Do I have to adapt the code somewhere ?

Comment: It could be a font issue, are you embedding any fonts? Otherwise, debug and verify that the PHP data is being loaded.

Comment: Not a font issue. I've put a `feedbackText.text` in the app in order to see what function was triggered and it doesn't load the loader... any idea why it does on my desktop and not on the Android device ? (this `loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete);` is not triggered)

Comment: Does the `URLLoader` give you an `ioError` or `securityError` event?

Comment: Any idea how I can load only the 30 first items for exemple, and then the user have to click on a button to load the other 30..etc ? (like "pages", cause it's possible that I'll have more that 200 items and they can't all fit in the TextField)

Comment: Hmm. It's been all day and I can't find the solution. If you read this, please can you help me with this problem ? many thx

Comment: Sorry this thread is getting a bit unwieldy long, I think you should start a new thread for further issues. Pagination can certainly be done.